# Condition on Upper Limit in Do To Loop

Tags: loops, sas

I am very new to SAS and have a basic question.

I am writing a macro containing a Do-To loop  from i = 1 to n. I want n to be conditioned on whether a year is less than 2005 or greater than it. If less than than n=10, otherwise n=11.

The year variable is already contained within the macro call so I feel like this should be easy but I'm struggling.

For example something like this code would be ideal:

```
%do i= 1 %to (if &year. < 2005 then 10; else 11)
```

This, however, does not seem to work. Is there another way I could easily implement this? Or use something similar to what's above?

Thanks! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem you can take advantage of the fact that SAS converts logical expressions to 0/1 results.

```
%do i= 1 %to %eval(10 + (&year >= 2005)) ;
```

For a more general condition just make another variable for the upper bound and use %IF/%THEN logic to set it.

```
%if &year < 2005 %then %let upper=10;
%else %let upper=11;
%do i= 1 %to &upper;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Such a basic solution.